# Ubuntu 18.04 applications thumbnails not showing properly in "Activities" overview

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

On pressing <kbd>super</kbd> key, applications thumbnails are rendering in weird manner.

[image: see attached screenshot]

I'm using Ubuntu dock (i.e. GNOME's dash-to-dock) to fix launcher at bottom.

extensions enabled on my system:

```
['alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
 'screenshot-window-sizer@hughsie.github.com',
 'native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
 'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
 'window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
 'pixel-saver@deadalnix.me',
 'windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
 'places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com', 
 'netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the [Native Window Placement](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/18/native-window-placement/) extension enabled, which lets you

> "*Arrange windows in overview in a more compact way*".

The specific window arrangement in your screenshot is due to this extension.

If you want to disable this arrangement, then disable/remove the Native Window Placement extension using *(GNOME) Tweaks* or from [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/). Alternatively launch Terminal and run

```
gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

and disable the extension.